# ZipArchive - Problem with the generated archive file

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I've got a problem with the class : ZipArchive.

My ZIP file is well created and my folders and files are in the archive.

However, I've got 2 problems:

- I can't extract a file from the generated archive unless if the file is located on the root of the archive;
- If I extract the entire archive, the tree is deleted, the files are all at the same level, while the tree is good if I browse the archive with an archive manager;

I've tried to creating the folders first with `$archive->addEmptyDir`, but it doesn't change anything.

I think that It's an Index problem or something like this but I'm not sure.

Here's my code:

```
$archive = new ZipArchive;

foreach($files as $file_origin_path) {
    if($error === FALSE) {
        $error = !$archive->addFile($file_origin_path, str_ireplace($path, '', $file_origin_path));
    }
}
$archive->close();
```

Would anyone have a way that would allow me to move forward?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ro/ziparchive.addemptydir.php#98621

Comment: Thankz for your comment Matei. I don't think that You have understood my problem. I know how to create an archive that keep the folders structure. The tree is well present in the archive, the problem happend when I extract the archive.